# Do things for all tibbles in environment

Tags: r, list, tibble

I have 110 tibbles in my environement. These tibbles are among other objects, but all tibbles have a common pattern. I know how to list them with `ls(pattern = MyPattern`). 
Now i need to do some basic work on each tibble. I have no idea at all how to handle this, as I will in fact work with a list of charcaters, not tibbles.
I tried to assign these tibbles in a new env, but wasn't successful when reading them. I got lots of errors.

Anyone with a solution to apply some work to my selected tibbles?

Comment: Yeah, don’t do that. Where do these 110 tibbles even come from? Have them in a list instead of your global environment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph they come from a csv with many steps to finally get these tibbles. Yes I want them to be stored in some kind of clean container.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) on putting data.frames into lists. My answer there returns a named list, which can be nice for referencing if the names of your tibbles have some meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` and `mget` to access things by name. So this, for example, should work:

```
lapply(mget(ls(, pattern=MyPattern)), nrow)
```

Comment: mget was the missing piece. TY, i will lapply myFun() then.